# discontinuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Prove or disprove.
If a function f is discontinuous at a point c then |f| is discontinuous at c.
I tried to graph and think about many discontinuous functions like: 1/x,√x   and sin 1/x in all the cases their absolute is also discontinuous. but how can we prove that without graph?

Comment: Consider cases where the discontinuity is the direct result of a sign change.

Comment: give examples you mean? there is no prove?

Comment: Well, if it is true then there will be a proof.  If it is false then all you need is a single counterexample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you define $f\colon\Bbb R\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ by$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }x\in\Bbb Q\\-1&\text{ otherwise,}\end{cases}$$then $f$ is discontinuous at *every* point of $\Bbb R$, but $|f|$ is continuous everywhere.